# Different style for same div in mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

I’ve got a `<div>` section in content body with a `<table>` inside, like below:

```
<div class="hub_specification">
example html table
</div>
```

**For Desktop view**, I’d like to show this `<div>` with 50% width of content area, floated left.

**For Mobile view**, I’d like to show this `<div>` with 100% width of content area, without any float.

So what will be the CSS code to decorate the `hub_specification` `<div>`?

It would be better if both ways were present: CSS for a file called `style.css` in WordPress *and* inline.

Comment: You should really consider [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and utilize its grid system with media specific classes. I am pretty sure that this is far not the last problem you will need to solve if you are working on an adaptive website, and the framework already has most of those thing figured out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not wrong do you want this? [click](https://jsfiddle.net/ay5u0ktb/2/embedded/result/)
**HTML**

```
<div class="hub_specification">
example html table
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hub_specification {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:20px;  
}
@media only screen and (max-width:350px) {
    .hub_specification {
    width:50%;
    background-color:oink;
    height:20px;  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `media queries`

```
.hub_specification{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .hub_specification {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
```

}

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp